# Why it shows ValueError even though I didn't remove items from the list that I loop over?

Tags: python

I found this problem in codewars basic fundamentals section.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/523f5d21c841566fde000009/train/python

```
def array_diff(a, b):
org_lst = list(a)
for i in b:
    for j in a:
        if i == j:
             org_lst.remove(j)
return org_lst

if __name__ == '__main__':
     print(array_diff([17, 13, -8, 17, 6, -3, -10, -14, -15, 14, -2, 15], [-19, -15, 13, 18, 15, -18, -10, -8, -18, -17, -2, 13, -3, -13, 4, 19]))
```

Complier shows **ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list**.What I am missing here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see 19 in the list? It is not present. So the program throws an error

Comment: This is a hideously inefficient way to do this.  But as for your bug, the value 13 occurs twice in `b`, but only once in `a`.  You're trying to remove it twice.  The second time produces an error, since it is no longer present in `org_lst` the second time.

Comment: @Sujay No, that's not the problem.  It's only trying to remove values that are in both `a` and `b`.  See my above comment for the problem case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I didn't have a slightest idea that an error may occur because of value occuring twice in `b`  but only once in `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second list "b" contains 13 twice and it get compared twice but the list "a" contains only one 13, thus produces ValueError

You may try this program

```
def array_diff(a, b):
org_lst = list(a)
print(org_lst)
for i in b:
    for j in a:
        if i == j:
            print(i,j)
            org_lst.remove(j)
            print(org_lst)
return org_lst
```

Output:
[17, 13, -8, 17, 6, -3, -10, -14, -15, 14, -2, 15]
-15 -15
[17, 13, -8, 17, 6, -3, -10, -14, 14, -2, 15]
13 13
[17, -8, 17, 6, -3, -10, -14, 14, -2, 15]
15 15
[17, -8, 17, 6, -3, -10, -14, 14, -2]
-10 -10
[17, -8, 17, 6, -3, -14, 14, -2]
-8 -8
[17, 17, 6, -3, -14, 14, -2]
-2 -2
[17, 17, 6, -3, -14, 14]
13 13
**Error**    org_lst.remove(j)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: I modified the code as 
    `for i in b:
        for j in a:
            if i == j:
                 a.remove(j)
    return a`                                                                                                                                 It works for the above test case but for ([1, 2, 2 ], [2] ) instead of [1] , it prints [1,2].Any suggestions?